# bootstrap 4 cards content overflow

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong with my layout? I am adding some controls to a card and the content overflows. I want the card to be as wide as the widest row...

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto p-4 ">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header"><h4>Find a contact</h4></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row flex-nowrap">
                    <div class="col-4 p-1 text-right">First:</div>
                    <div class="col-8 p-1"><input type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row p-1 flex-nowrap">
                    <div class="col-4 p-1 text-right">Last:</div>
                    <div class="col-8 p-1"><input type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row p-1 flex-nowrap">
                    <div class="col-4 p-1 text-right">Compnay:</div>
                    <div class="col-8 p-1"><input type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row p-1">
                    <div class="col-8 p-1 offset-4 text-nowrap"><input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-sm m-2"/>My contacts only: <input id="checkBox" type="checkbox[enter link description here][1]"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <div class="row ">
                    <div class="col"><a href="#">more search</a></div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/msz2ndkr/21/

Comment: Is this you want? https://jsfiddle.net/raj_mutant/msz2ndkr/37/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your html is the following line:

```
       <div class="row p-1">
            <div class="col-8 p-1 offset-4 text-nowrap"><input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-sm m-2"/>My contacts only: <input id="checkBox" type="checkbox"/></div>
        </div>
```

Bootstrap assumes 12 columns and you have specified 8 columns (col-8). All your other rows have 12. Also, get rid of the  `offset-4`. Here is my solution:

```
        <div class="row p-1">
            <div class="col-12 p-1 text-nowrap"><input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-sm m-2"/>My contacts only: <input id="checkBox" type="checkbox"/></div>
        </div>
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/msz2ndkr/40/)

Comment: This doesn't work. The controls still overflow in IE and the button is aligned with the first column instead of being aligned under the text box

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: By the way IE11 only partially supports flexbox (bootstrap 4 is based on flexbox). https://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: I am testing in Chrome, IE 11 and Edge. I guess I will have to stick with normal column split...

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with how 'width: auto' is calculated and set on certain elements and their parents. Try making your nowrap container a flexbox and set some width for it's children like: 
`

```
.nowrap-elems-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

`
https://jsfiddle.net/a0godL7b/25/

it's not too elegant but it should work